# android firebase query sub-object across multiple objects

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to find a session with a specific id (not key) without knowing the user id.

**Database Structure**

[image: Database Structure]

I had an initial attempt by looping through all the children of users and creating a new reference every time but it is not working and I can't figure out why nor I know if it should work in the first place.

```
 database.child("users").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for(DataSnapshot snap : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                        database.child("users").child(snap.getKey()).child("sessions")
                                .orderByChild("id").equalTo(id)
                                .limitToFirst(1)
                                .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot data) {
                                        if (data.exists()) {
                                            Session session = data.getValue(Session.class);
                                        }
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                                    }
                        });
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
```

Comment: You may use `log` to be more specific where your issue is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole idea of what you are trying to do is correct but you have a single mistake. Your last `reference` is wrong. When you are trying to iterate the second time you are missing a child. You need to add `.child(sessionId)`. To solve this, please use this code:

```
database.child("users").child(snap.getKey()).child("sessions").child(sessionId)
                            .orderByChild("id").equalTo(id)
                            .limitToFirst(1)
```

In which `sessionId` is the second unique id generated by the `push()` method.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help. The whole point of what I was trying to do is that I don't have the `sessionId`. I only have the more user friendly `id`, which is not the same thing, and I'm trying to find `sessionId` (well actually get the whole session).

Comment: You have the `sessionId`, as i see it in your database. Is the unique key under the `sessions` node. To get it, use the `getKey()` on your reference in the exact moment when you are using the second `push()` method. Having that `sessionId`, you'll be able to use it in your `DatabaseReference`.

Answer (score 0):

Issue caused by permission denied from Firebase.